# update xnph44s to xnph05q

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, oneplus-one

the problem:

I am using a OnePlus One. Current CM version - 11.0 XNPH44S. I got the update notification to XNPH05Q and when i click "download update" it downloads the update(i dont know where). And when i click "install update" it reboots and automatically goes to CM recovery mode(i dont need to press the power and volume down button).

As most of the forums suggested, I do the following:

Apply update > choose from internal Storage > 0/

but i dont find the correct file to select. And so I simply reboot the system and download the file cm-bacon-5fa8c79c0b-to-5229c4ef56-signed.zip and put it in the internal storage.. then i do the following:

reboot (automatically goes to cm recovery)
apply update
choose from internal storage
0/
select the zip file

the installation starts[image: and then it shows "installation failed" error]...

Same problem has been posted [here at xda-developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/help/update-xnph05q-please-help-t3031383) but no solution is given... also, i tried the instructions from [the forum of oneplus one](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/instructions-xnph05q-for-all-users-locked-or-unlocked-bootloader.265788/).

Note: i dont have much idea on flashing twrp, etc.... you can consider me a noob.

HELP!

**My solution:**

The problem lied in the ROM installed in my phone. So, I rooted the phone, installed TWRP recovery, flashed SU binary and then flashed the updated ROM.

The most easiest way to root is given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhKrp6Gyjfs&index=1&list=PL_Oacuq9_7sc4OBuVjiXX5RcVBy0qDaLX). After following the video tutorial, download the ROM you want to install then flash it using the TWRP recovery.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Recovery mode, select Install,  look for the ZIP file and select  Install zip.

Comment: That is what I did if you read the question properly.